# Count frequencies if values of other column are equal to specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

```
City            Job
London          Webdesigner
London          Webdesigner
Tokio           Lawyer
Tokio           Teacher
Buenos Aires    Manager
London          Athlet
Rome            Doctor
London          Webdesigner
```

I'm looking for a way to count the frequency of `Webdesigner` if "City" is equal to `London` (in same row). The result of the formula should be `3`.

Comment: Nope.. I just spelled wrong here. It's correct in Excel. :)

Comment: What do you mean "Frequency of Jobs" ?   I tried this, and get "3" ... probably not exactly what you want, so please clarify:  `=COUNTIF(C:C,C2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `City` is in A1 please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"London",B:B,"Webdesigner")
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10="London")*(B1:B10="webdesigner"))
```

Comment: Actually the double-unary isn't necessary there, since you are multiplying the two arrays.